# Segmentation Fault in JPG Recovery Program (pointer/ array problem i assume) C

Tags: c, pointers, cs50

Writing a program in C that recovers "lost" JPG's from the raw data of a memory card. I feel pretty confident with my overall code and logic, correct me if I'm wrong, but im getting a segmentation fault upon runtime.

I'm assuming the issue lies in my buffer array. My goal was to make a buffer array of type int8_t (one byte) that is 512 long, and then repeatedly reading a block from the memory card into it again and again, deleting the previous block when a new one is written. I'm thinking maybe instead of replacing the old block, it just adds onto it and exceeds my 512 array. Here's my code, any thoughts?

Also I've tried making another buffer as a pointer, and malloc'ing 512 bytes of data to it but also didnt work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover <filename>\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // Remember file name and open, checking if it opened correctly
    char *file_name = argv[1];
    FILE *input = fopen(file_name, "r");

    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("file <%s> could not be opened\n", file_name);
        return 1;
    }
    // initialize buffer and other variables/types
    typedef uint8_t BYTE;

    int BLOCK_SIZE = 512;

    BYTE buffer[512];

    int JPEG_COUNTER = 0;

    FILE *img = NULL;
    // check if at end of memory card
    while (fread(&buffer, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, input) == BLOCK_SIZE)
    {   // check if a new JPG has started
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0)
        {   //check if the first JPG on card, or start of sequential ones, initialize and write into new file from buffer
            if (JPEG_COUNTER < 1)
            {
                fread(&buffer, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, input);
                char *file_name = malloc(17 * sizeof(char));
                if (file_name == NULL)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                sprintf(file_name, "%.3i.jpg", JPEG_COUNTER);
                img = fopen(file_name, "w");
                fwrite(&buffer, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, img);
                JPEG_COUNTER++;
            }
            else
            {
                fclose(img);
                fread(&buffer, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, input);
                sprintf(file_name, "%.3i.jpg", JPEG_COUNTER);
                img = fopen(file_name, "w");
                fwrite(&buffer, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, img);
                JPEG_COUNTER++;


            }
        }
        // continue writing onto unfinished JPG
        else
        {
            fread(&buffer, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, input);
            fwrite(&buffer, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, img);
        }
    }
    free(file_name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which line does your debugger say the fault happened on?

Comment: The code seems complicated enough to leave room for logic errors. You only need to call `fread()` and `fwrite()` *once* per loop.

Comment: You have two variables named `file_name`. The one that's allocated with `malloc()` is inside an `if` block. But `free(file_name)` is outside that block, so you're trying to call `free()` on `char *file_name = argv[1];`. Since `argv[1]` is not dynamically allocated, that's UB.

Comment: I assume this is the cs50 task? Your program has far too many reads and writes and loses data. Read a block, if it is the start of an image then close the existing output file if it is open and open the next file, then write the block unconditionally. Do not use `malloc` for the filename, just use a regular array as you used for `buffer`.

Comment: segmentation fault usually indicates that you are trying to access a memory out of arrays allocated ex: initialize `int a[5]` and trying to access `printf("%d",a[5])` so suggest you to use a debugger and try where exactly your code is getting wrong

Comment: It's weird to be passing `&buffer` to `fread`.  Just pass `buffer`, which has type `char *`.  Similarly for `fwrite`.  You don't need to be taking the address of an array in this code.

Comment: I also wonder about `malloc(17 * sizeof(char))`. Why do you think filenames can only be 16 characters?

Comment: In the `else` block, `file_name` also refers to `argv[1]`. If the result of `sprintf()` is longer than the argument, you'll overflow.

Comment: As a summary: avoid reusing variable names, and be careful about variable scope.

Comment: `if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0)` is also incorrect for the last comparison. Try `(buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0` instead.

Comment: So a few changes, @Barmar declared img outside of the loop and changed argv[1] to input_file, removed all '&' (as its a pointer it's unnecessary i believe?). Still getting error. Honestly would have a go at valgrind and debugging myself but have to run VS code locally and haven't gotten debugger to work yet.

Comment: Simplify it. Call `fread()` once, examine it, close and open files if required, then write the block as the last line of the loop. After the loop close any file (if open).

Comment: Please revise question with sample input so we can reproduce this.

Comment: Upper case symbols are, by convention, constants (enum values or symbolic).

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code and ran into a bunch of challenges as it pertains to attempting to identify and issues to get the program to more closely work as intended.

The first issue was identifying that that first block of a read file is for a "jpg" file.  Adding in some "printf" statements provides listed output at the terminal that also could be viewed via a debugger.

```
    while (fread(&buffer, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, input) == BLOCK_SIZE)
    {   // check if a new JPG has started
        printf("Here is what is in the start of the buffer: %x  %x  %x  %x\n", buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3]);
        printf("buffer[3] & 0xf0 results in a value of %d\n", (buffer[3] & 0xf0));
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0)
```

Along with those additional "printf" statements, another "printf" statement was added in the "else" block that is allegedly printing subsequent blocks of data to the output file.

```
        else
        {
            printf("Continue writing blocks after the first block\n");
            fread(&buffer, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, input);
            fwrite(&buffer, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, img);
        }
```

With those additional bits of information, what immediately shows up is that first four bytes of the first read data block do not meet the test conditions of program even though the fourth byte is the actual value in the "jpg" file used for testing.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Recover/bin/Release$ ./Recover cat.jpg
Here is what is in the start of the buffer: ff  d8  ff  e0
buffer[3] & 0xf0 results in a value of 224
Continue writing blocks after the first block
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Performing the "and" operation to the fourth byte did not result in the expected value of zero, and so the opening of the output file does not occur, and subsequently, when a write to that file is attempted, undefined behavior happens as a "write" is being pushed to most likely a NULL pointer.

So, refactoring that test to only check the first three bytes does initially define the output file pointer ("img") and begin writing data to the output file.  However, when the reading and writing cycle is completed, the program utilizes a "free" function which is not the correct operation, resulting in another program dump.

```
    printf("Exited the while loop\n");
    free(file_name);
    return 0;

Continue writing blocks after the first block
Here is what is in the start of the buffer: 5  83  8f  ca
buffer[3] & 0xf0 results in a value of 192
Continue writing blocks after the first block
Exited the while loop
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

In lieu of the "free" function, the "fclose" statement would be substituted.

```
    printf("Exited the while loop\n");
    fclose(img);
    return 0;
```

With these initial bits of refactoring, the program does indeed run to completion and create a file.  However, when attempting to view the created file with an image viewing utility, the file will not properly open.

```
Could not load image '000.jpg'
```

Also, when viewing the size properties of the created file, it is roughly half the size of the original input file being tested.

```
File size of cat.jpg:   136.6 kb
File size of 000.jpg     68.1 kb
```

This is due to the fact that the input file is actually being read twice for every file write within the "while" loop.

With all of that, I took a step back and looked at where "reads" and "writes" should occur within the "while" loop.  Following is a refactored version of the code to address many of the issues to at least provide a functional file copy program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BLOCK_SIZE 512

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover <filename>\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // Remember file name and open, checking if it opened correctly
    char *file_name = argv[1];
    FILE *input = fopen(file_name, "r");
    int x;      /* Used this to handle any last block size that is not 512 bytes    */

    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("file <%s> could not be opened\n", file_name);
        return 1;
    }
    // initialize buffer and other variables/types
    typedef uint8_t BYTE;

    BYTE buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];

    int jpeg_counter = 0;

    FILE *img = NULL;
    // check if at end of memory card
    while (1)                                       /* Simplify while loop logic                */
    {
        x = fread(buffer, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, input);    /* Check if at the end of the memory card   */
        printf("Block size read: %d\n", x);         /* Added for debug information              */
        if (x != BLOCK_SIZE)                        /* Final partial block writing              */
        {
            fwrite(buffer, 1, x, img);
            break;                                  /* Exit the while loop here                 */
        }
        // Check if a new JPG has started
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && buffer[3] == 0xe0)   /* ff d8 ff e0  were found as the first bytes of a jpeg file    */
        {
            //check if the first JPG on card, or start of sequential ones, initialize and write into new file from buffer
            if (jpeg_counter < 1)
            {
                printf("jpeg_counter: %d\n", jpeg_counter);     /* Added for debug information  */
                //fread(buffer, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, input);
                char *file_name = malloc(17 * sizeof(char));
                if (file_name == NULL)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                sprintf(file_name, "%.3i.jpg", jpeg_counter);
                img = fopen(file_name, "w");
                fwrite(buffer, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, img);
                jpeg_counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("jpeg_counter: %d\n", jpeg_counter);     /* Added for debug information  */
                fclose(img);
                //fread(buffer, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, input);
                sprintf(file_name, "%.3i.jpg", jpeg_counter);
                img = fopen(file_name, "w");
                fwrite(buffer, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, img);
                jpeg_counter++;
            }
        }
        // Continue writing onto unfinished JPG
        else
        {
            printf("Reading and writing file\n");               /* Added for debug information  */
            fwrite(buffer, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, img);
        }
    }
    fclose(input);  /* Close the files  */
    fclose(img);
    return 0;
}
```

My apologies for including the total program as the refactoring spanned the full program.  Following are the key points.

- As noted in the good comments earlier, variables are usually lower case and values such as "BUFFER_SIZE" are defined as constants which was done here.
- When using a character array such as "buffer", the name as is would be the pointer to the array, so the ampersand should not be used in the "fread" and "fwrite" functions.
- To correct for the double reading that was occurring during the "while" loop cycle, the "while" loop was simplified, the reading of each block of data was moved to the beginning of the loop, and when last block of data was read, then the loop was exited with a "break" statement to handle a block of data that is less than the expected block of 512 bytes.

The result of this was the executing the program produced a copy of the "jpg" file being used for the test.  The file sizes matched and the new file could be opened and viewed with an image viewer utility.

As is, this program would either copy an actual "jpg" file or have a segmentation fault if some other type of file was read.  So, there is still room for improvement.  Hopefully, this provides some idea of what was working and what was not working.  The take-away from this is probably delving some more into "C" tutorial literature as it pertains to file processing (open, read, write, and so forth), "while" loop processing, and byte sequences for image files such as "jpg" files.